# Epic fantasy with one good female twin and one evil male twin?

Tags: identify-this-movie, fantasy

A few years ago I saw an epic fantasy movie involving two twins. I think the twins were elves. The female twin was good and the male twin was evil. They were connected, so that hurting one of them would also hurt the other. The good twin had some powerful magical artifact that the evil twin was trying to get ahold of. There was a big battle at the end in some kind of place with clockwork. The female twin finally stabbed herself to kill her brother.

I think it had CG, so it should be relatively modern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be *[Hellboy II - The Golden Army](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0411477/)*.

From the synopsis: Hellboy fights against the prince across the entire chamber, at one point finally gaining the upper hand. But he refuses to take the Prince's life. As they fight, Nuala feels the wounds that Hellboy inflicts upon her brother. Nuada prepares to stab Hellboy in the back, but suddenly collapses from pain in his chest. Nuala is revealed to have stabbed herself in the heart in a final attempt to stop her brother.